# Commented out HTML visible in Inspect Elements, Why?

Tags: html, magento

I have commented out a line in HTML in Magento store however when I go to Chrome and click on Inspect Elements, I still see the code but its commented out.

What can I  do to prevent the HTML code i have commented out to make it invisible from Inspect Elements ?

I don't want to delete the commented out section in case I will need it later on.

Any solutions ?

Comment: Don’t use an HTML comment, but a server-side comment in PHP or whatever templating syntax/language is used.

Answer (score 4):

HTML comments are part of an HTML document. They are not rendered for display by the browser, but they are part of the document sent from the server to the client machine.  Thus HTML comments are visible when inspecting element or when viewing the source.

I believe Magento store is written in PHP and you could comment out the line in the php file like this

```
<?php
/*
line to comment out
*/
?>
```

The HTML document the PHP sends back to the browser will not contain that comment.

Comment: I am also trying to Comment out some text lines on Magneto Home page... I go to Magento --> CMS-- Pages-->homepage folder and since everything there is in HTML, I cannot use php based comment code as you guys first suggested.. I have to use <!-- text --> for HTML... and this code is visible in Inspect Elements. What can I do?

Comment: in that case I would recommend making a copy of the file so you still have a copy of the lines you don't want.  Then just remove the lines you were commenting out.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is manipulated or processed in client side so the comments can be visible while inspecting.To remove this comment either do not comment in HTML or if you need that comment you can comment that code using PHP.

The comments in PHP is not showed while inspecting because server process that as a comment and only respond the required things to the client not the comment.

Hope this make you clear.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't using the HTML comment tag. You can do it using server side comment that already suggested by others.

If you want to use HTML comment tag, the best way is to *never put your sensitive code on the Internet at all*.